# Access Response Headers from spotify-web-api-node call

Tags: node.js, spotify

Using the [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) client to access [Spotify's web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/), is it possible to access the Response Headers from a call?

i.e. I'd like to access the `Cache-Control` header value when using the clients `getAlbum` method.

Comment: Internally it is calling restler (rest api). so raw response specific property can not be handled from usage level...

Comment: Restler provides access to the raw response data (https://github.com/danwrong/restler#parsers), so that shouldn't prevent the client author from also providing access to the raw response headers.

Comment: is the ``spotify-node`` api providing so? then only the response header can be handled..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access the header using the wrapper methods at this point in time, but I've added an [enhancement issue on Github](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/issues/24) and will have a look at it shortly.

Update: The headers are now available from version 2.0.0.